# Camel Aws move a file with acl public

Tags: java, kotlin, amazon-s3, apache-camel

I want to move a file from one bucket to another bucket with camel, the code works but what i can't do is make the url public.

This is my code:

```
from(uri)
        .routeId(routeId)
        .process {

            CamelExchangeUtils.setS3UrlToExchange(it, url)

            // set relevant headers, copyObject needs these set to work properly
            it.getIn().setHeader("CamelAwsS3BucketDestinationName", targetBucket)
            it.getIn().setHeader("CamelAwsS3DestinationKey", targetPath)
            it.getIn().setHeader("CamelAwsS3CannedAcl", CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead)
        }
        .to("$targetUri&operation=copyObject")
```